# Fetching a portion of HTML from SQL table

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an sql table where I am saving the HTML of asp.net MVC 3 view. I want to fetch a portion of HTML from this saved HTML. Is there any SQL/ LINQ function which can be used in this scenario. Other option is to get all the HTML from table and then parse it and fetch specific portion/div. Is there any free HTML library which can be used in this case ?

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe fetching the entire HTML will be your only option as I'm not aware of any SQL commands that are HTML savvy.

Once you get it, you may find [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) useful in parsing out what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I see that HTML agility Pack is used If we give path of HTML file. Can It work with HTML which I will get from the table.

Comment: Yes, I haven't used it much but I believe you can use doc.LoadHtml(html_string) to load directly from your database instead of from a URL with doc.Load(url) or from a filepath.